# How can I clear and reset the buffer in Terminal?

Tags: applications, pantheon-terminal

Due to the way Terminal clears the screen with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut, I'm unfortunately finding myself using other terminals for most things.

I work with logs a lot, and need to be able to quickly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to Select All and copy text into some other app. If I can clear the buffer, I can easily get the text I need without all the unrelated history.

Unfortunately as Terminal leaves the buffer in place when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, Select All contains the entire session's history, not just the recent logs. This is a big deal with you're trying to view the last 500 lines of a command line session that has 10k lines.

I understand that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> is just clear screen, and so also clearing the buffer might be something entirely different, but the lack of this is slowing me down. Thanks for your great work!

Comment: Relevant feature request: https://github.com/elementary/terminal/issues/181

Answer (score 5):

The `reset` command might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work unless I'm able to enter the `reset` command into the terminal. For example, if running a local webserver, to enter `reset` I'd need to stop the server to enter the command.

Comment: Can you put your task in background mode (Ctrl+Z), do `reset` (and eventually put it back into the foreground with `fg`) ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way IMO is to install a terminal you're already used to that already has that function. In my case, I installed gnome-terminal:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`

then ran these two commands to make it the default:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec gnome-terminal
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg`

Since I'm used to the cmd+k key to clear the terminal in macOS, I added `Super+K` (Super is the windows key) as a shortcut combination for `Reset and Clear`